# Selecting last item in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So say I have an array and the user can add do it by a input html tag:

```
var example=["a","b"];
var command=document.getElementByID("id");
```

so idk how long the array will be when i execute the next step,which is selecting the last item in the array and register it in an object

```
example.split(",")
someObject[//how do i chose the last item?]
```

Comment: `arr.slice().pop()`

Comment: `someObject[someObject.length - 1];`

Comment: ``arr[arr.length - 1]``

Comment: @Daniel_L Oh what a wasteful thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the last item in a `javascript` array like this

```
arr = example.split(",");
lastArr = arr[arr.length - 1];
```